# My thesis focus or My thesis' focus

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

I would like to describe the main focus of my thesis. However, I do not know which one is correct:

**My thesis focus is on ...**

or

**My thesis' focus is on...**

Comment: "My thesis focuses on..." is probably better than the two above

Answer (score -1):

Since it is "the focus of my thesis", the correct way is "My thesis' focus"